# Any tips for a plugin to define specific pages navigation for specific types of users / members?

Tags: plugins, membership, plugin-members

Is there a plugin for Wordpress to define sort of a membership program?
My requirement is to have registered users, basically members, and according to their (paid) plan, they can have access to some specific areas of my website.

Currently I found https://wordpress.org/plugins/wishlist/ but I was wondering if there are other plugins on the market. So I can evaluate pro and cons of more than one plugin and target my best choice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you're going to have this ticket shut down, as plugin recommendations are outside of the scope of this forum..

Comment: I was in doubt about it, you are right, but while creating the question I saw some few other questions about plugin, so I thought, let's give it a try... thanks anyway for the heads-up for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display a different menu then use the below Plugin, Define the different roles for each plan, and set menu/navigation accordingly.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-menus/

For the Membership plan, I guess you already set up the membership plugin or you can use the [Paid Membership Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/) plugin